# How to add a button using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, django, bootstrap-modal

I'm new to Django and bootstrap and currently working on a project. Basically my question is purely on html and css. I want to insert a button on the right side of the box. I use the following code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-right">
  <a href="{% url 'listing' listing.id %}" class="btn btn-info">More Info</a>
</div>
```

However i get:

[image: Using above code]

[image: Without the above code]

As you can see there is a gap because of the button, how can i put this button without this gap.

Code from the html file:

```
                    <!--Listing One-->
                    {% if listings %}
                        {% for listing in listings %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="feat_property list">
                                <div class="thumb">
                                    <img class="img-whp" src="{{ listing.photo_main.url }}" alt="fp1.jpg">
                                    <div class="thmb_cntnt">
                                        <ul class="icon mb0">
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-transfer-1"></span></a></li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-heart"></span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <div class="tc_content">
                                        <div class="dtls_headr">
                                            <ul class="tag">
                                                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">{{ listing.available }}</a></li>
                                                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">{{ listing.is_featured }}</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <a class="fp_price" href="#">€{{ listing.price | intcomma }}<small>/mo</small></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="text-thm">{{ listing.property_type }}</p>
                                        <h4>{{ listing.title }}</h4>
                                        <p><span class="flaticon-placeholder"></span> {{ listing.address }}, {{ listing.city }}, {{ listing.zipcode }}</p>
                                        <ul class="prop_details mb0">
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Beds: {{ listing.bedrooms }}</a></li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Baths: {{ listing.bathrooms }}</a></li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Sq Ft: {{ listing.sqft }}</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                                        <a href="{% url 'listing' listing.id %}" class="btn btn-info">More Info</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="fp_footer">
                                        <ul class="fp_meta float-left mb0">
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><img src="images/property/pposter1.png" alt="pposter1.png"></a></li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">{{ listing.realtor }}</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="fp_pdate float-right">{{ listing.list_date | timesince }}</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <p>No Listings Available</p>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                        <!--End Listing One-->
```

[image]

After adding:

```
    <div class="row mx-0">
    <ul class="prop_details mb0 col-10">
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Beds: {{ listing.bedrooms }}</a></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Baths: {{ listing.bathrooms }}</a></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Sq Ft: {{ listing.sqft }}</a></li>
  </ul>
    <div class="col-2"><a href="{% url 'listing' listing.id %}" class="btn btn-info">More Info</a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you add your custom class for "More Info" button and use it in css? If yes, you can just add `margin-top: -10px;`. Play with value `-10` and you'll get what you want

Comment: Are you refering to gap on the left of your button ? Please share your whole code to help you clearly

Comment: @MaxiGui Yes, i mean the gap on the left of the button. I added code from html file.

Comment: give a proper one code for your question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gap is due to col-12 that is over the link. This col-12 will act like row and take the full width of the container. So in your case, html is well showing what you are asking.

To correct that I would suggest to set ul next to button. `|       ul      | button |`

What I suggest you is to set it this way next to your ul:

```
<div class="row mx-0">
   <ul class="prop_details mb0 col-10">
      <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Beds: {{ listing.bedrooms }}</a></li>
      <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Baths: {{ listing.bathrooms }}</a></li>
      <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Sq Ft: {{ listing.sqft }}</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="col-2"><a href="{% url 'listing' listing.id %}" class="btn btn-info">More Info</a></div>
</div>
```

So I set `ul` and your link into a div with `row mx-0` class. Then I add `col-10`to your `ul` and `col-2` to a `a` container to make button more flexible.

after you can set class `align-middle` to your `li` to make sure that they stay in the middle verticaly

TO correct: I saw you were using class `mb0`, but I guess you meant: `mb-0`

### DEMO

```css
.img-whp{         /* ONLY CREATED HERE BECAUSE CLASS NOT PROVIDED */
  max-width:50px; /* ONLY CREATED HERE BECAUSE CLASS NOT PROVIDED */
}                 /* ONLY CREATED HERE BECAUSE CLASS NOT PROVIDED */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--Listing One-->
  {% if listings %}
    {% for listing in listings %}
  <div class="row mx-0">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="feat_property list">
        <div class="thumb">
          <img class="img-whp" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/14/47/man-5557864_960_720.jpg" alt="fp1.jpg">
          <div class="thmb_cntnt">
            <ul class="icon mb0">
              <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-transfer-1"></span></a></li>
              <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-heart"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <div class="tc_content">
            <div class="dtls_headr">
              <ul class="tag">
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">{{ listing.available }}</a></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">{{ listing.is_featured }}</a></li>
              </ul>
              <a class="fp_price" href="#">€{{ listing.price | intcomma }}<small>/mo</small></a>
            </div>
            <p class="text-thm">{{ listing.property_type }}</p>
            <h4>{{ listing.title }}</h4>
            <p><span class="flaticon-placeholder"></span> {{ listing.address }}, {{ listing.city }}, {{ listing.zipcode }}</p>
            <div class="row mx-0">
              <ul class="prop_details mb0 col-10">
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Beds: {{ listing.bedrooms }}</a></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Baths: {{ listing.bathrooms }}</a></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Sq Ft: {{ listing.sqft }}</a></li>
              </ul>
             <div class="col-2"><a href="{% url 'listing' listing.id %}" class="btn btn-info">More Info</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="fp_footer row">
            <ul class="fp_meta float-left mb0">
              <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><img src="images/property/pposter1.png" alt="pposter1.png"></a></li>
              <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">{{ listing.realtor }}</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="fp_pdate float-right">{{ listing.list_date | timesince }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p>No Listings Available</p>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
    <!--End Listing One-->
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I added what you proposed however i got, see screenshot above. Do i have to change also style.css file?

Comment: @paniklas Try to add: `row` there `<div class="fp_footer row"></div>` and share the class of your footer, please

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what gap you are referring to

if you mean the margin (gap around the outside area around the button) try `style="margin:0px;"`

if you dont want padding (gap on the inside of the button) try
`style="padding:0px;`

If you mean the gap (from left to right) try
`style="width:100%;"`

Also if you mean the gap on the space on the right side, you can also use `style="float:left"`

what float left does is it moves it to the right-side of the previous div putting it 'next to' the div

Comment: I mean the gap on the left of the button. Where do i have to use  style="width:100%;" in the html file or the css file? Can you show me where should i put it? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The gap you have is the padding from the container. You basically need to add a negative margin on the right side of the button and that will fix the issue.

Cheers!